# Prove that is $A$ is skew-symmetric, then $X^TAX = 0$ for all $X = [x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n]^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-polynomials

Recall that a matrix $A$ is *skew-symmetric* if and only if $A^T = -A$. Prove that if $A$ is skew-symmetric, then $X^TAX = 0$ for all $X = [x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n]^T$

Comment: Only in characteristic $\neq 2$...

Answer (score 6):

Note that $X^TAX$ is a scalar, so $X^TAX=(X^TAX)^T=X^TA^TX$

but $A^T=-A$, so $X^TAX=X^T(-A)X\Rightarrow2X^TAX=0\Rightarrow X^TAX=0$

Answer (score 4):

$$
X^T A X = \sum_{i,j}x_iA_{ij}x_j = \sum_{i,j}x_jA_{ji}x_i= - \sum_{i,j}x_jA_{ij}x_i = -\sum_{i,j}x_iA_{ij}x_j = -X^TAX=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

***Whoops!  In my haste I took $X$ to be a matrix!  But you can get the gist of it:***

First, the way it *should* be done:

$X^TAX = (X^TAX)^T = X^TA^TX = -X^TAX \Rightarrow X^TAX = 0, \tag{0}$

assuming we are not over a field of characteristic $2$, since for *vectors* $X$, $X^TAX$ is a *scalar* quantity, whence the leftmost equality in the above binds. ***QED***

As I said, I neglected the little $T$ in the upper right corner of $X = [x_1, x_2, . . ., x_n]^T$ and so took the $x_i$ to be the columns of $X$; I think I'd best get some rest!
But in unedited form, here's what I got:

This is not true, as taking $X = I$ and

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \tag{1}$

illustrates.  In this case

$X^TAX = A \ne 0. \tag{2}$

What *is true* is that

$x_i^TAx_i = 0 \tag{3}$

for each column $x_i$ of $X$, since

$(X^TAX)^T = X^TA^TX = -X^TAX, \tag{4}$

which shows that $X^TAX$ is skew-symmetric; now note that for any columns of $X$, $x_i$ and $x_j$, $x_j^TAx_i$ is a scalar; indeed $(X^TAX)_{ji} = x_j^TAx_i$ but the skew-symmetry of $X^TAX$ forces its diagonal entries to vanish, whence (3).  And that's about as far as I can take it!

***Whew!  Sleepy Time!***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: How do you conclude with that $x^TAx = -x^TAx $ returns 0?

Is it as simple as moving $-x^TAx $ to the left so we end up with:
$2 x^TAx = 0$ and dividing with the scalar 2 on both sides so that:
$ x^TAx = 0$

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.  Cheers!